# "times 510-($-$$) db 0" not working with my codes

Tags: assembly, nasm

So the code that works fine and produce a 512 bits file is bellow

```
    org 07c00h
    mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    call    DispStr
    jmp $
DispStr:
    mov ax, BootMessage
    mov bp, ax
    mov cx, 16
    mov ax, 01301h
    mov bx, 000ch
    mov dl, 0
    int 10h
    ret
BootMessage:        db  "Hello, OS world!"
times   510-($-$$)  db  0
dw  0xaa55
```

Then I add few lines and the bin file is 540 bits, which make no sense, the only way to fix this is do times 380 db 0 , which I do the calculation

The nonsense code is bellow

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7c00]

jmp     Main

PrintTill0:
lodsb
cmp     al,0
je      Return
mov     ah,0eh
int     10h
jmp     PrintTill0

PrintWithLength:
mov     ah,13h
int     10h
jmp     Return

Return:
ret

Main:
mov     si,msg1
call    PrintTill0

cli
push    SEGment msg2
pop     es
mov     bp,msg2
sti
loop1:
mov     cx,9
call    PrintWithLength
inc     bl
jmp     loop1

cli
hlt


msg1:    db  "Hello, AInoob~~~",0Dh,0Ah,"The future is in your hand, so, what do you want to do?",0Dh,0Ah,0h
msg2:    db  "AInoob~~~"

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on? This really drives me crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to store the segment base of `msg2` into `es`, and the keyword you're looking for is just `SEG`, not `SEGMENT`. Unfortunately, flat binary outputs do not support this, so you need a different solution.

Instead, since you know `msg2` is not going to be beyond address `0x10000`, you can just set `es` to zero:

```
xor ax, ax
mov es, ax
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but when I tried SEG, it says binary output format does not support segment base references, no matter I remove Times xxx db 0 or not.